# How do I take a URL in a Doc and replace it with the image that URL points to using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I am capturing the URL (along with additional information) in a Form. That form exports to a Sheet which triggers GAS that finds/replaces placeholders in a Doc template with information in the Sheet. What I would like to do is replace the URL in the doc after the first GAS runs with a second one that only captures the URL, pulls the image and replaces the URL with that image.

The DocID will never be the same. My thought is to associate the GAS with the template file which is used to create all Docs so it will (should?) be associated with all copies. I hope that makes sense. Thank you for any information you can pass along!

```
//logo URL coming from Sheet 
var logo = e.values[4]; // fetching the image from the URL 
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(logo); 
var fileBlob = response.getBlob(); 
var res = ImgApp.getSize(fileBlob); 
Logger.log(fileBlob); //Attempt to get image into document 
body.replaceText('{{blob}}', fileBlob);
```

Comment: Do all of the Urls in the document get replaced with an image?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Each document will have a single URL that should be replaced with the image the URL links to. I think I can pull the URL using Fetch, but I am having trouble getting the image into my document.

Comment: Is the image going to be presized for the document?

Comment: I don't care too much, right now, about sizing. Ideally though, I think every image should be pulled into the image in the same size. However,for now, I would be happy to get the image into the document!

Comment: So we ought to do whatever were going to do in your script.  Because your going to use the url to get the image and then we want to take the image from there and put it into the document thus removing the original link.  So can you paste what code you already have so that we can tie them together properly.

Comment: // logo URL coming from Sheet
  var logo = e.values[4];
  
// fetching the image from the URL
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(logo);
  var fileBlob = response.getBlob();
  //var res = ImgApp.getSize(fileBlob);
  Logger.log(fileBlob);
  
//Attempt to get image into document
  body.replaceText('{{blob}}', fileBlob);

Comment: is the image coming from a form submission?

Comment: Yes, the URL is one of about 14 different fields all coming from the Form -> Sheet -> GAS -> Doc

Comment: And one final question.  When you refer to the doc are you actually referring to a spreadsheet?

Comment: Feel free to ask as many questions as you need - I truly appreciate the help! No, the endpoint is a Doc. The Sheet is just the place where the Form responses go. Once the response is added to the Sheet the GAS is triggered which takes the information from the Sheet to the Doc.

Comment: Could you able to share a sample of what you want to do? Your code will not work, if you want to insert an image you cannot use the `replaceText` method, you will need to get the position, and then insert it with [`appendInlineImage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#appendinlineimageimage)

Comment: Thank you! Looks like the appendInlineImage command was the one I needed. Now, I just need to figure out how to adjust the size. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments the function you are using right now [`replaceText`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement) will not work trying to replace a blob as you intend.

The correct way would be to use another function like [`insertInlineImage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#insertinlineimagechildindex,-image) or [`appendInlineImage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#appendinlineimageimage).

Also you were takling about changing its size, you have another function applied to the `InlineImage` object called [`setWidth`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/inline-image#setwidthwidth)